# RSS code in Mailchimp - is there a way to manipulate the code?

Tags: wordpress, rss, mailchimp

I've been using this code via RSS items in Mail chimp:

  |RSSITEMS:|
- |RSSITEM:TITLE|
  |END:RSSITEMS|

Which drags the feed through like so: (see image)
However - I want to be able to 
a. space between each story
b. take out the underline
c. increase the size of the text.

Is there something I can do in the customer code Rss items in mail chimp? If so what would it be? Or do I have to create a new feed to specify these things?

Thanks in advance!
C

I've looked at different ways of changing the code in the custom Rss but I think its going to be a brand new feed created - never done that before but willing to learn.